# Samba share with read only permission

Tags: samba, share

I want to share a folder to the network with just readonly permission.
Every one can see and read the contents in the file .But no one should edit.

How the samba configuration will be ?

My Current configuration for another share is

```
[IN_USER]
    path = /thehive/WWW/user
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    valid users = user
    write list = user
```

Answer (score 4):

> read only = no

```
read only = yes
```

The [documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#READONLY) is your friend.

Comment: @shodanshokIf onl people would read them themselves rather than relying on the SF RMaaS.

Comment: I did.But, still I am able to write inside the folder.

Comment: I tried this too, I can still edit files in the folder (even after rebooting the server).